# How to install plugin for single store in multi store setup?

Tags: magento2, extensions, plugin

I have a plugin, that I only need installed against a single store in a multistore Magento 2 setup.

Installing via composer appears to install the plugin globally across all storefronts, I can work out how to configure different credentials for the plugin on a per store basis, but not remove it from the other stores entirely.

Answer (score 2):

> There is no way to install a plugin for specific store. Plugin will
>   install globally.
>
> If your module has enable / disable functionality then you can disable
>   that module for specific store from admin configuration.
>
> Select the store view from the switcher and disable that module for
>   that store.

[image]